# Cannot resolve variable in for loop

Tags: java, dictionary

Maybe a simple question for you but I'm stuck.
Why can't the `i` be resolved to a variable?

```
Map<Integer, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();

List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

for(Integer i : integers);
{
    String str = testMap.get(i); //i cannot be resolved to a variable
}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Mistakes were made, thank you

Comment: @Dongo not **mistakes** but **mistake**

Comment: @SpringLearner http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistakes_were_made

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are ending the for loop with the `;` before the {} block, so i is no longer in scope.

Change

```
for(Integer i : integers);
{
    String str = testMap.get(i);
}
```

to

```
for(Integer i : integers)
{
    String str = testMap.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the semicolon

```
for(Integer i : integers)
```

as the semicolon will not allow your code to be executed in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(Integer i : integers);
{
    String str = testMap.get(i); //i cannot be resolved to a variable
}
```

the semicolon(;) at the end means end of statement.This is similar to

```
for(Integer i : integers)
{

}
{
    String str = testMap.get(i); //i cannot be resolved to a variable
}
```

As you can see `i` is out of for loop,so compiler will complain about it(i can not be resolved to a variable

so remove ;